# how do I write code in accord with the tasks

Tags: python, matrix, numbers

a matrix is given:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8,
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1,
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9,
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2,
1 3 5 7 9 7 5 3,
3 1 5 3 2 6 5 7,
1 7 5 9 7 3 1 5,
2 6 3 5 1 7 3 2.
```

Define a structure for storing the matrix.

1. Write code that swaps the first and last rows of the matrix.
2. Write the code for creating a matrix of any size, filled with zeros (the size is set via the console).
3. Write a code that will count how many times the number 3 occurs in the matrix.

I tried solving this but My teacher says the following code is wrong. Where is my mistake??

```
matr = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
        [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2],
        [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 7, 5, 3],
        [3, 1, 5, 3, 2, 6, 5, 7],
        [1, 7, 5, 9, 7, 3, 1, 5],
        [2, 6, 3, 5, 1, 7, 3, 2]]
def will_swap_first_and_last_rows(matr):
    matr[len(matr) - 1], matr[0] = matr[0], matr[len(matr) - 1]
    return matr
 
def will_craete_matrix_of_any_size_filled_with_zeros():
    m = int(input('Enter the number of rows of the matrix '))
    n = int(input('enter the number of columns of the matrix '))
    return [[0] * m for i in range(n)]
 
def will_count_how_many_times_the_number_3_occurs_in_the_matrix(matr):
    s = 0
    for row in matr:
        for elem in row:
            if elem == 3:
                s += 1
    return s
 
print(*will_swap_first_and_last_rows(matr), sep='\n')
print(will_craete_matrix_of_any_size_filled_with_zeros())
print(will_count_how_many_times_the_number_3_occurs_in_the_matrix(matr))
```

Comment: If the teacher really just answered "is wrong" then he/she missed a good chance to show his/her knowledge of didactics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has `rows (m)` and `columns (n)` swapped. Do it like this:

```
return [[0] * n for i in range(m)]
```